# nested child view event LayoutView Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, marionette

Below is the hierarchy of my LayoutView
LayoutView > Region > CollectionView > ItemView > checkbox

If I want to listen to change event of checkbox at LayoutView level, should I listen and trigger the event at each level or is there a shorter way of implementing the same.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you want is childEvents in your LayoutView. http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.2/marionette.layoutview.html#layoutview-childevents

And just trigger your event in your child view like normal.

Comment: the event name changes as it goes up. example: CollectionView prepends "itemview:" to the child events

Comment: a jsbin snippet would be appreciated

Comment: To expand on slinhart's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867089/marionette-bubble-event-from-itemview-to-parent-layoutview#